# Enable a form field on form submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 <%= f.text_area :snippet, class: "snippy-area", :rows=>15,
                                :place_holder=> "Create a Snip....", :name 
                                => "user_name", :disabled => true %>
```

How would I enable the form field on form submission. Below is my jQuery code which is not working for some `odd reasons`.

```
$('#edit_user_form').submit(function(){
   $("user_edit_text").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Below is my DOM.

```
<textarea class="snippy-area" disabled="disabled" id="user_edit_text" name="edit_form_user" rows="15">        
sdsdsdsdsdgffgfg123345sdsdsd</textarea>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Explain issue better and post relvant HTML markup as rendered in DOM. BTW, what is this selector `"user_edit_text"` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff: I have updated the DOM element as rendered by rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="snippy-area" disabled="disabled" id="user_edit_text" name="edit_form_user" rows="15">        
    sdsdsdsdsdgffgfg123345sdsdsd
</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#user_edit_text").prop("disabled",false);
```

You forgot to precede selector for your textarea with `#` since you are using its ID, so `$("#user_edit_text")` would be the selector for your textarea which is having ID as `user_edit_text`.

FYI, Similarly if you want to select a class name then you'l need to precede class name with `.`

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Tmgb/)

Comment: NO, there is difference dude. see properly. if you want to use `ID` as a selector then you must have to precede it with `#`

Answer (score 0):

use `Id` or `class name` to remove `dissabled` property

and also try with `removeAttr("dissabled");`